# What is the use of `<{}>` in javascript class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what's the difference between:

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
```

vs.

```
export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component<{}> {
```

Comment: The latter uses a generic.

Comment: Second example is invalid es syntax. It seems it uses flowtype or typescript

Comment: I have just compiled it. It works fine with react/jsx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's type syntax from a javascript parser / compiler. The `{}` braces represent an empty object with the properties that you can assign to it.

https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627

For example `Animal extends Component<{name: string, age: number}>` would mean that such Animal component accepts a name property as a string and age as a number. You can use it as expected:

```
<Animal name="Toby" age={3} />
```

Such syntax would be invalid ES6 by default. Exactly as in the case of JSX, that is not plain javascript either. Your code is working thanks to the react environment you are working with.

Type systems in javascript are meant for development / release cycle. If you ignore types and warnings but the rest of your javascript code is valid, you won't ever notice. Read more about [flow](https://flow.org/) and [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks @jsdario .